# Variable inside BroadcastReceiver class can't use it outside

Tags: java, android

I have a `Broadcast Receiver` to get a String value from a Service and then I start another Service.

The code is :

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver entryIdReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        entry_id = intent.getStringExtra(ENTRY_ID);
        startVideoService();
    }
};


private void startVideoService() {
    Intent intentService = new Intent(this, VideoService.class);
    intentService.putExtra(ENTRY_ID, entry_id);
    startService(intentService);

}
```

and it's in my `MainActivity`.

The problem is that I tried to run this code a lot of times and always the entry_id in the Service class was null !
I then changed the above code to pass the entry_id in startVideoService() as a param and it worked.

The code that works :

```
        private final BroadcastReceiver entryIdReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        entry_id = intent.getStringExtra(ENTRY_ID);
        startVideoService(entry_id);
    }
};


private void startVideoService(String entry_id) {
    Intent intentService = new Intent(this, VideoService.class);
    intentService.putExtra(ENTRY_ID, entry_id);
    startService(intentService);

}
```

I can't understand why the first version above didn't work. Since entry_id is a variable with scope outside of `BroadcastReceiver` shouldn't that work ?

Comment: I am not sure how you send ENTRY_ID to the broadcast receiver. Are you using LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroacastIntent() in your first service  ?

Comment: Yes I do. There's nothing wrong there. I print the variable just after I get it from the receiver and I can confirm its OK.

Comment: Can you show full Activity class code in case 1 ?

Comment: It's too big. The thing is I don't use entry_id variable in any other place and since I now pass it as a parameter my IDE flags it that can be convert to local.

Comment: your broadcast receiver probably created a new instance of entry_id and startVideoService was referencing another.